# ReactJS - React ContextMenu: Menu Appear behind scrollbar

Tags: reactjs

I am using [React ContextMenu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contextmenu) in one of my projects.

When i use the context menu on a div that has overflow: scroll, the menu appears behind the scrollbar. Does anyone know how to make it appear over the scrollbar?

[image]

### Version

2.13.0

### Steps to reproduce

Create a div
specify a widh and height
add some content to that the div shows scrolling
try to right click near the scroll area
menu appears behind scrollbar

### Expected Behavior

Menu should appear over scrollbar

### Actual Behavior

menu appears behind scrollbar

Comment: Cannot reproduce, maybe should you create a fiddle, and specify your browser...

Answer (score 0):

you can use npm i react-perfect-scrollbar , example:

```
<div className=" z-40 w-screen lg:w-3/12 xl:w-3/12 flex flex-col items-center fixed bg-gray-300 p-4 h-screen left-0 top-0 lg:left-auto xl:left-auto lg:top-auto xl:top-auto lg:h-10/12 xl:h-10/12 rounded-lg">
                    <PerfectScrollbar className="w-full px-4">
                    <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center w-full">
                        <h1 className="text-gray-800 text-2xl text-center my-2 flex-1">Amigos</h1>
                        <svg className="h-10 w-10 fill-current text-gray-800" viewBox="0 0 20 20" onClick={()=> setFriends(false)}>
                            <path d="M10.185,1.417c-4.741,0-8.583,3.842-8.583,8.583c0,4.74,3.842,8.582,8.583,8.582S18.768,14.74,18.768,10C18.768,5.259,14.926,1.417,10.185,1.417 M10.185,17.68c-4.235,0-7.679-3.445-7.679-7.68c0-4.235,3.444-7.679,7.679-7.679S17.864,5.765,17.864,10C17.864,14.234,14.42,17.68,10.185,17.68 M10.824,10l2.842-2.844c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.46,0-0.637c-0.177-0.178-0.461-0.178-0.637,0l-2.844,2.841L7.341,6.52c-0.176-0.178-0.46-0.178-0.637,0c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637L9.546,10l-2.841,2.844c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0l2.844-2.841l2.844,2.841c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.461,0-0.637L10.824,10z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    {amigos.map((u)=>(
                        <>
                            <div className="w-full">
                            <ContextMenuTrigger style={{width: '100%'}} id={u._id}>
                                <div className={`flex flex-row items-center rounded-full shadow-lg ${u.online ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500'} w-11/12 my-2 mx-auto`}>
                                    <Avatar size="50"  round={true} src={u.img} name={u.nombre}/>
                                    <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                                    <h1 className="text-base text-white mx-3">{u.nombre}</h1>
                                        <p className="text-sm text-gray-700">{u.online ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContextMenuTrigger>
                            </div>
                            <ContextMenu preventHideOnScroll={false} className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg p-2 px-4" style={{zIndex: 1003}} id={u._id}>
                                <MenuItem data={{action: 'ver',user: u}} onClick={handleClickMenu}>
                                    <h1 className="text-gray-800 text-base my-2">Ver perfil</h1>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem data={{action: 'enviar',user: u}} onClick={handleClickMenu}>
                                    <h1 className="text-gray-800 text-base my-2">Enviar mensaje</h1>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem data={{action: 'eliminar',user: u}} onClick={handleClickMenu}>
                                    <h1 className="text-red-500 text-base my-2">Eliminar amigo</h1>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </>
                    ))}
                    </PerfectScrollbar>
                </div>
```